# Django CRUD doesn't reloads the model

Tags: python, django, crud

When I do a crud action to my database it won't change on the website after refreshing the page. I have to restart the server "python manage.py runserver" everytime to see the changes on my website.

I asked another student about this problem and he said he didn't had the problem. I tried to find it on the internet but with no success.

***It's add the richting but doesn't show it until I do python manage.py runserver.***

richtingen.html (where I add a richting and show the richting)

```
{% extends 'main_app/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block main %}
    <main>
        <div class="messages">
            <h2>Richtingen</h2>
            <h3>Nieuwe richting maken:</h3>
            <form class="all_forms" action="post_richting/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Verzenden</button>
            </div>
        </form>
            <hr>
            <div class="messages">
            {% for richting in richtingen %}
                <h3 id="{{richting.id}}">{{richting.naam}}</h3>
                <p>{{richting.omschrijving}}</p>
                <a href="wijzigen/{{richting.id}}">Wijzigen</a>
                <a href="verwijderen/{{richting.id}}">Verwijderen</a>
                <hr>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^[rR]ichtingen/$', views.richtingen, name='richtingen'),

url(r'^richtingen/post_richting/$', views.post_richting, name='post_richting'),
```

views.py

```
titel = 'KA Go Malle'
volledigeTitel = 'Koninklijk Atheneum Go Malle'
richtingenObjects = Richtingen.objects.all()


def richtingen(request):
    form = RichtingForm()
    context = {'titel': titel,
        'volledigeTitel': volledigeTitel,
        'form': form,
        'richtingen': richtingenObjects}
     return render(request, 'main_app/richtingen.html', context)


def post_richting(request):
    form = RichtingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save(commit = True)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/richtingen')
```

Comment: Please try to make an [mcve] of what you actually do when you do a crud action

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes of course we need the code. In particular, the code that is querying and displaying the values that aren't changing.

Comment: Where are `richtingenObjects`, `volledigeTitel` and `titel` coming from? They don't seem to be defined.

Comment: changed it @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the relevant data outside a function. I'm not sure why you have done this, but that means the query only evaluated once: when the module is first loaded. Don't do this; define the variables inside the function that uses them, so that the query is made ever time.

Comment: haven't thought about that, I used that query multiple times so I thought I shouldn't repeat writing it so I made it once public :D my mistake